# Update view after background job finishes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to Rails. I have a background job that runs and takes about a minute. I want to display message on the view after the job is complete. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is really no simple solution for this one, I'll give you few ideas how you could handle this problem.

1. Simplest solution would be to just send an email to user when job finishes. I know this is not what you asked for but this is a quick and easy way to inform user some long running process is done.
2. You could make an API endpoint that returns state of the task and then use javascript to poll that endpoint every X seconds. Exact implementation of this varies depending on what that background job is.
3. You could use something like [websocket-rails](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails) to open 2 way connection with the browser. This way you could send message to the browser to update view once the background job is done.

Comment: @Daborius My background job launches AWS ec2 instance and returns a string of instance id. As soon as job finishes I want to print the id into the view. Is that possible?

Comment: I believe it is with this thing, but I never tried to actually implement it https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails